# Putty automatic connection script

Tags: ssh, connection, script, putty

I created a script to connect automatically to my Raspberry using putty :

```
start /D "C:\Program Files\PuTTY\" putty.exe -ssh 192.168.1.104 -l pi -pw mypassword
```

But it doesn't load properly, it does use the pi username but I get an access denied for the password it then asks me for another password as you can see :

```
Using username "pi".
Access denied
pi@192.168.1.104's password:
```

When I type the exact same password it let me access the Raspberry.

Do you know what I did wrong ? Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works fine on my machine.
Are you using any special characters in you password?

Try using quotation marks at your password in the script.

> `start /D "C:\Program Files\PuTTY\" putty.exe -ssh 192.168.1.104 -l pi
>   -pw "mypassword"`

Some characters in Windows command line have specific meaning i.e. `@`, `$`, `!`, `%`, `=`, `\`, so you could easily output another string as password argument, or form an [escape sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequence).

For example, `%0`-`%9` would output arguments no. 0 - no. 9 passed to the batch script file, `%cd%` would print current path.

Here is a table of escape sequences used in Windows batch script files.

`` +-------------------------+-----------------+
| Character to be escaped | Escape Sequence |
+-------------------------+-----------------+
| %                       | %%              |
| ^                       | ^^              |
| &                       | ^&              |
| <                       | ^<              |
| >                       | ^>              |
| |                       | ^|              |
| '                       | ^'              |
| `                       | ^`              |
| ,                       | ^,              |
| ;                       | ^;              |
| =                       | ^=              |
| (                       | ^(              |
| )                       | ^)              |
| !                       | ^^!             |
| "                       | ""              |
| \                       | \\              |
| [                       | \[              |
| ]                       | \]              |
| "                       | \"              |
| .                       | \.              |
| *                       | \*              |
| ?                       | \?              |
+-------------------------+-----------------+ ``

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ok yes thank you ! I have a "&" in my password. I added the " and now it works fine ! :)